# Remove grey box around button

Tags: html, css, button

As the title says, I am having trouble removing the grey box that surrounds my button. I have tried using `outline: none` but didn't work.

You can see it here ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j6m9nmub/)):

```css
.btn-group {
  background: #4abdac;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4abdac, 4abdac);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4abdac, 4abdac);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4abdac, 4abdac);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4abdac, 4abdac);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4abdac, 4abdac);
  -webkit-border-radius: 33;
  -moz-border-radius: 33;
  border-radius: 33px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div><button><a class="btn-group" style="color: #000;" href="www.example.com"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Example Text&nbsp;</span></a></button></div>
```

Comment: remove button tag

Comment: yup got it sorry didn't even notice thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your question you don't remove the default style of the buttons, that's why you've got the gray background. You can remove that with this style:

```
button {
   border:none;
   background-color:transparent;
   outline:none;
}
```

Then you don't need to use an anchor tag inside the button - just call like this:

```css
.btn-group {
  background: #4abdac;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4abdac, 4abdac);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4abdac, 4abdac);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4abdac, 4abdac);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4abdac, 4abdac);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4abdac, 4abdac);
  -webkit-border-radius: 33;
  -moz-border-radius: 33;
  border-radius: 33px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<div>
<button class="btn-group" onclick="window.location.href='www.example.com'">Example Text</button>
</div>
```

Comment: cool thanks ill replace it with that - still a newbie so all tips help

Comment: @Mangolicious tick this answer if this answer is use full to you

Comment: `transperant` should be `transparent`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `button` tag like that :

https://jsfiddle.net/Lsjgdt4d/

Answer (score 0):

just replace your code with

```
<style>
.btn-group {
  background: #4abdac;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4abdac, 4abdac);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4abdac, 4abdac);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4abdac, 4abdac);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4abdac, 4abdac);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4abdac, 4abdac);
  -webkit-border-radius: 33;
  -moz-border-radius: 33;
  border-radius: 33px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
<div>
<a class="btn-group" style="color: #000;" href="www.example.com"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Example Text&nbsp;</span></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this css along with your css code

```
button{
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

apply style to the button element and supress the div :

```
<a  style="color: #000;" href="www.example.com"><button class="btn-group">
<span style="color: #ffffff;">Example Text&nbsp;</span></button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove button tag and add style display:inline-block to a tag. Because a tag is inline element. we have to change block element set style as display:inline-block.

```css
.btn-group {
  background: #4abdac;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4abdac, 4abdac);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4abdac, 4abdac);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4abdac, 4abdac);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4abdac, 4abdac);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4abdac, 4abdac);
  -webkit-border-radius: 33;
  -moz-border-radius: 33;
  border-radius: 33px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top:10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div><a class="btn-group" style="color: #000;" href="www.example.com"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Example Text&nbsp;</span></a></div>
```